# Sum of values in list when condition is met

Tags: python, list

I have a python list `l` containing instances of the class `Element`:

```py
class Element:
    def __init__(self, id, value):
        self.id = id
        self.value = value

l = [Element(1, 100), Element(1, 200), Element(2, 1), Element(3, 4), Element(3, 4)]
```

Now I want to sum all `value` members of the classes `Elements` if their `id` is equal to obtain this list:

```py
l = [Element(1, 300), Element(2, 1), Element(3, 8)]
```

What is the most pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is (almost?) nothing that `itertools` cannot do. Take a look at [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter


class Element:
    def __init__(self, id, value):
        self.id = id
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):  # kudos @mesejo
        return "Element({}, {})".format(self.id, self.value)

l = [Element(1, 100), Element(1, 200), Element(2, 1), Element(3, 4), Element(3, 4)]

l.sort(key=attrgetter('id'))  # if it is already sorted by 'id', comment-out

res = [Element(g, sum(sub.value for sub in k)) for g, k in groupby(l, key=attrgetter('id'))]
```

which results in:

```
print(res)   # [Element(1, 300), Element(2, 1), Element(3, 8)]
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this requires the list to be sorted by `id` already.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to create a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) that maps ids to sums of values.  Then we can take those results and use them to build a new list of `Elements`.  One way to do that is to use [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) to map the items of that dictionary to the arguments to `Element`

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import starmap

class Element:
    def __init__(self, id, value):
        self.id = id
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Element({}, {})".format(self.id, self.value)

l = [Element(1, 100), Element(1, 200), Element(2, 1), Element(3, 4), Element(3, 4)]

d = defaultdict(int)

for e in l:
    d[e.id] += e.value

print(list(starmap(Element, d.items())))
# [Element(1, 300), Element(2, 1), Element(3, 8)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also get the desired result using `set` to get just the unique ids and `sum` to total the values. For example:

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self, id, value):
        self.id = id
        self.value = value

l = [Element(1, 100), Element(1, 200), Element(2, 1), Element(3, 4), Element(3, 4)]

ids = set(elem.id for elem in l)
totals = [Element(i, sum(elem.value for elem in l if elem.id == i)) for i in ids]
# [Element(1, 300), Element(2, 1), Element(3, 8)]
```